# Is there a pthread equivalent to WatiForMultipleObjects

Tags: pthreads

I have the following Windows code that spawns two threads then waits until they have both completed:

```
hThreads[0] = _beginthread(&do_a, 0, p_args_a);
hThreads[1] = _beginthread(&do_b, 0, p_args_b);
WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);
```

I am now porting the same code to use pthreads but am unsure how to do the equivalent of `WaitForMultipleObjects`:

```
pthread_create(&hThreads[0], 0, &do_a, p_args_a);
pthread_create(&hThreads[1], 0, &do_b, p_args_b);
???
```

Is there an equivalent way, using pthreads, to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to wait for all, as you're doing here, you can simply call `pthread_join()` for each thread.  It will accomplish the same thing.

```
pthread_create(&hThreads[0], 0, &do_a, p_args_a);
pthread_create(&hThreads[1], 0, &do_b, p_args_b);

pthread_join(hThreads[0], NULL);
pthread_join(hThreads[1], NULL);
```

You can get fancy and do this in a for loop if you've got more than a couple of threads.

Comment: Some further reading ... pthread_exit is only really required to pass information back to the pthread_join call waiting for the thread to exit?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your comment.  No, you don't need to call `pthread_exit` unless that it more convenient.  It's analogous to calling `exit` from `main`.  You can do so if you want, but you can also just return normally, and the effect will be as if you had called `pthread_exit` with the return value from the thread function.  I almost never call `pthread_exit`.  I also almost never use the return value (hence why I pass NULL as the second arg to `pthread_join`).

Answer (score 1):

I always just used a for loop with pthread_join

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<threads;i++)
    pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
```